# Change MS Excel cell fill color without vba macro

Tags: excel

I thought I'd post this somewhere because it took me a bit to figure out how to change a cell's fill color in MS Excel. What happened was that I had changed a cell's fill color by assigning one through the Custom tab of the Fill Color option. I later realized that I wanted to use the same color for other cells, but had no way of duplicating this custom color, as this selection wasn't saved anywhere. My searches resulted in creating a macro (vba) code, but my installation of MS Excel doesn't allow use of macros.

Comment: .....not sure if that is the right place for this.....

Answer (score 1):

So the way I was able to do this was by clicking on the cell with the desired fill color, clicking on the drop down next to "Fill Color" menu option, selecting "More Colors", selecting the "Custom" tab and applying the same values for "Color model", "Red", "Green", and "Blue" to the cell where you'd like the same fill color:
[image]

[image]

I hope this is helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Or you could use Format Painter? Honestly I'm not sure this question belongs on SO.

Comment: If the cell has other formatting that is the same, You could also copy it and paste just the format (i.e., paste special) which should include the color.